# Typescript return type possibilities of a resolved promise

Tags: node.js, typescript, promise, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

I want to use a strict return type statement in Typescript.
When I write a function with a single if-then-else statement, the TS Linter of vscode is smart enough to see accept my return value:

[image: IfThenElseWorks]

If I try to do the same if a single .then().catch() block, in which there aren't any other possibilites for the function to go, my linter won't accept the return type.

[image: Error Message in VsCode]

Returning the promise won't work aswell (as intended)

[image: Return promise]

I also checked with a .finally() statement, which doesn't work aswell and isn't intended to be used in my situation.

Source:

```
var myPromise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    if (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1) {
        resolve("yay")
    } else {
        reject("nay")
    }
});

function returnYayOrNay(): string {
    myPromise
        .then((result) => {
            return result
        })
        .catch((result) => {
            return result
        })
}
```

**Edit 1: I want to return a string as in Picture2**

Comment: A promise is async in nature, you cannot return synchronously from it.

Comment: Not a dupe, but you definitely need to read it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @IngoBürk You want to say that including a minor async call would need a rewrite of my complete sync codebase?

Comment: There's async await. I'm telling you that you cannot synchronously return a result that is only known asynchronously. We can't travel through time.

Answer (score 2):

> By default, the return type of a promise is `Promise<{}>`. So, You can typecast the promise return value.

```
var myPromise = new Promise<string>(function (resolve, reject) {
   if (Math.round(Math.random()) == 1) {
      resolve("yay")
   } else {
      reject("nay")
   }
});
```

> In the Above example, the return value becomes `Promise<string>`.

Comment: Goal is to return a string. Not a Promise<string>.

Comment: @ErnstErnst every promise function returns a type binded inside a promise. once you use an `await` or use the `then` the type binded inside the promise is retrieved. So, in this case, string is returned inside the `then`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the `returnYayOrNay` function is that it does not return a string. When you use `then` and `catch` of a promise you are passing in a function (an anonymous arrow function `=>`). So `return result` just return from this anonymous function.

My guess is that you want to return the value of `myPromise`. You can't return this directly as when `returnYayOrNay` is called the value of `myPromise` may not yet available. So `returnYayOrNay` should also return a promise.

Also `myPromise` is typed by default to `Promise{}` as typescript can't infer the type of the result based on the usage of `resolve` and `reject`

That being said, you have several options :

Return the new promise crated by the `then`, `catch` calls:

```
function returnYayOrNay() {
    return myPromise
        .then((result) => {
            return result
        })
        .catch((result : string) => {
            return result
        })
}
```

Use async/await

```
async function returnYayOrNay() {
    try{
        return await myPromise;
    }catch(e) {
        return e as string;
    }
}
```

Comment: neither of them work because in the both solutions typescript forces the return of the function to be Promise<any> and in the first return is local to the promise's callback